# Set Pass/fail based on 10 answers from each of many individuals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2011

I'm trying to output a Pass/Fail indicator for each student. A new student is on every row and their 10 answers are logged from Column E to N.

[image: Link to picture of data]

I want to match their answers with the 10 correct answers in Column S to AB, count them, and then have the word `Pass` show in the results Column O if they have a 70% pass rate, and `fail` if they are under that 70%.

All help appreciated.

Comment: As long as the number of columns is the same (E:N=10 cols, S:AB=10 cols), the comparison to a range with the answer set should not matter, e.g. in O3 `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(S$14:AB$14=E3:N3))>6,"Pass","Fail")`. For readability I would suggest is putting the answer key into a column (S14:S23) and using `TRANSPOSE` like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(S$14:S$23=TRANSPOSE(E3:N3))). `TRANSPOSE` adds an extra level of processing and this `SUMPRODUCT` requires **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

Comment: What is the -- syntax? (I can't find any obvious reference elsewhere and it's quite awkward to Google!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a separate row for the answers but in matching columns:

[image: SO27682763 example]

then something like:

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(E$1:N$1=E3:N3))>6,"Pass","fail")
```

As @Jeeped points out, the correct answers could be left where they are with only a small adjustment to the formula above but (apart from the lurid colours!) I think the layout shown is neater and possibly more useful.